# Using a filesystem in place of a Database to perform quick lookups

Tags: database, database-design, hashtable, big-o

I was recently posed a simple question to which I responded with an unusual answer. I suspect my answer was particularly bad but am not certain what the performance characteristics truly would be.

Suppose you are given inputs each in the form of a hash code (just a bunch of bits.) Uniquely corresponding to each hash code is an integer value which you would like to return. Your system knows the most likely queries and caches them in memory. For the remaining, less frequent lookups you will have to access a hard drive (disk I/O.) There exists a least recently used policy to replace the cache in memory but that shouldn't be terribly important here.

For the hashes on disk, the conventional way to store them would be in a Database (keyed on the hashes) in a tree shape.  This would grant you O(log(n)) lookup time once at the database stage.

My answer seemed odd to the asker and a little odd to me.  Suppose instead of a database, you simply kept the values on disk in a file system with a directory structure that exactly mirrored the bits of the hash values.  For instance, if we had three bit hashes (and only had entries for `100 => 42` and `010 => 314159` your file system would look like:

`\0
  .\00
    .\000
    .\100
      42.justanumber
  .\10
    .\010
      314159.justanumber
    .\110
\1
  .\01
    .\001
    .\101
  .\11
    .\011
    .\111`

The `x.justanumber` files are empty. The filenames themselves contain the information you're looking for.

Further assume that updates never occur (the entire DB/file system is re-written weekly.) I'd think that a filesystem set up this way would give you `O(1)` lookup time instead of the `O(log(n))` lookup time of a tree-based DB. Am I missing something? Why would this not be preferable?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've come to an answer.

If the system always uses a folder for every possible bit combination and you have a 32-bit hash, you will have `2^32` folders at the outer layer and roughly the same amount within all inner layers so you'll have `2^33` folders each of size 4kB due to page size limitations. Additionally, each "empty" hash file will occupy 4kB on disk for the same reason. So assuming, let's say, 5% occupancy you would have:

`2^33 * 4kB + 2^32 * 4kB * 0.05 = 35.22 TB` of storage needed.

The savings are `O(1)` lookup time instead of `O(log(# hashes))` lookup time which almost certainly doesn't justify the storage space requirements. (Also remember this is for the uncommon case where you have a memory/cache miss.)

Admittedly, if you only created the minimum number of folders needed to support the 5% occupancy you'd end up with less space needed. The exact number of folders needed would depend on the distribution of the hashes.  Assuming a good hash function, this should be close to random, which I believe means we'll end up needing the majority of the inner layers and definitely 5% of the outermost layers of directories.  This instead gives something like:

`2^32 * 4 kB * 0.05 + 2^32 * 4kB * 0.40 + 2^32 * 4kB * 0.05 = 8.59 TB`

...which is still way too much space for such a simple thing.  (I made up the 40% figure for the inner folders. If anyone can come up with a rigorous figure there, please comment/answer.)